# Android map application crashes on emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, google-play-services, google-maps-api-2

I have created a very basic android map activity application after installing Android Studio and installing all the needed SDKs for my platform, google play services and google repository from the SDK Manager.
But when I launch the app regardless of the API level I set for my device I get a message "SampleApplication won't run unless you update Google Play services" with an Update button as soon as the emulator launches.
Clicking on the update button crashes the application and I see this in the logs:

```
08-20 13:07:35.225    1768-1768/? D/dalvikvm? Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on) 08-20 13:07:35.565    
1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp E/Trace? error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2) 08-20 13:07:35.875    
1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp I/dalvikvm? Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, 
referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza 08-20 13:07:35.875    
1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp W/dalvikvm? VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 242: 
Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder; 08-20 13:07:35.875    
1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp D/dalvikvm? VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00c2 08-20 13:07:35.885    
1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp I/dalvikvm? DexOpt: access denied from Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil; 
to field Landroid/app/Notification;.extras 08-20 13:07:35.885    
1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp W/dalvikvm? VFY: unable to resolve instance field 18 08-20 13:07:35.885    
1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp D/dalvikvm? VFY: replacing opcode 0x54 at 0x00e1 08-20 13:07:35.895    
1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp E/dalvikvm? Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', 
referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza 08-20 13:07:35.895    
1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp W/dalvikvm? VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 25 (Landroid/app/AppOpsManager;) 
in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil; 08-20 13:07:35.895    
1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp D/dalvikvm? VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000e 08-20 13:07:35.905    
1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp I/dalvikvm? Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller,
referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzh 08-20 13:07:35.905    
1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp W/dalvikvm? VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 532:
Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller; 08-20 13:07:35.905    
1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp D/dalvikvm? VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b 08-20 13:07:35.935    
1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp W/GooglePlayServicesUtil? Google Play services out of date.  
Requires 7571000 but found 3136130 08-20 13:07:35.946    1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp W/GooglePlayServicesUtil? Google Play services out of date.  
Requires 7571000 but found 3136130 08-20 13:07:35.955    1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp W/GooglePlayServicesUtil? Google Play services out of date.  
Requires 7571000 but found 3136130 08-20 13:07:35.965    1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp W/GooglePlayServicesUtil? Google Play services out of date.  
Requires 7571000 but found 3136130 08-20 13:07:35.975    1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp W/GooglePlayServicesUtil? Google Play services out of date.  
Requires 7571000 but found 3136130 08-20 13:07:35.985    1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp W/GooglePlayServicesUtil? Google Play services out of date.  
Requires 7571000 but found 3136130 08-20 13:07:36.005    1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp W/GooglePlayServicesUtil? Google Play services out of date.  
Requires 7571000 but found 3136130 08-20 13:07:36.015    1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp W/GooglePlayServicesUtil? Google Play services out of date.  
Requires 7571000 but found 3136130 08-20 13:07:36.035    1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp W/GooglePlayServicesUtil? Google Play services out of date.  
Requires 7571000 but found 3136130 08-20 13:07:36.085    1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp W/GooglePlayServicesUtil? Google Play services out of date.  
Requires 7571000 but found 3136130 08-20 13:07:36.106    1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp W/GooglePlayServicesUtil? Google Play services out of date.  
Requires 7571000 but found 3136130 08-20 13:07:36.135    1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp W/GooglePlayServicesUtil? Google Play services out of date.  
Requires 7571000 but found 3136130 08-20 13:07:36.156    1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp W/GooglePlayServicesUtil? Google Play services out of date.  
Requires 7571000 but found 3136130 08-20 13:07:36.185    1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp W/GooglePlayServicesUtil? Google Play services out of date.  
Requires 7571000 but found 3136130 08-20 13:07:36.205    1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp W/GooglePlayServicesUtil? Google Play services out of date.  
Requires 7571000 but found 3136130 08-20 13:07:36.355    1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp D/libEGL? loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so 08-20 13:07:36.355    
1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp D/libEGL? loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so 08-20 13:07:36.376    
1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp D/libEGL? loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so 08-20 13:07:36.396    
1768-1772/example.com.sampleMapApp D/dalvikvm? GC_CONCURRENT freed 259K, 12% free 2510K/2832K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 141ms 08-20 13:07:36.405  
1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp D/? HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a139d08, tid 1768 08-20 13:07:36.515    
1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp W/EGL_emulation? eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented 08-20 13:07:36.556    
1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp D/OpenGLRenderer? Enabling debug mode 0 08-20 13:08:57.456    
1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp D/AndroidRuntime? Shutting down VM 08-20 13:08:57.456    
1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp W/dalvikvm? threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930) 08-20 13:08:57.496    
1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:820)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
            at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$5.onClick(Unknown Source)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 08-20 13:09:00.516    1768-1768/? I/Process? Sending signal. PID: 1768 SIG: 9"

After seeing this ("Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7571000 but found 3136130")  in the log,
I have tried installing the Google play services apk com.google.android.gms-v7.5.74 by using the terminal's "adb install" command to no avail.
```

Please help me find out what am I missing.

PS: I have searched lot of other related questions on SO about this, but they all more or less point to the fact that the google play services might not be installed.

Answer (score 1):

Your error clearly says

```
1768-1768/example.com.sampleMapApp W/GooglePlayServicesUtil? Google Play services out of date.
```

Go to SDK manage and update your Google API and create a new emulator.

Comment: Thank you, I think I have already tried this. I'll check again though.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve my issue by choosing "Lollipop 22 x86 Google APIs" for my emulator. Before this I was using Lollipop 22 x86_64 Android 5.1.1 for my target. Adding Google APIs in the target and updating all pending updates for my SDK solved this for me.
Edit: Also there were lot of other SDKs for different flavours of android present which I had to clean up and only retain API levels 19 and above for this to work.